# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'NSLayoutConstraint for <GADBannerView:

Tags: swift, xcode

シミュレーションした直後に　アプリケーションが停止されます。広告の貼り方に問題があるようなのですが、どこに問題があるのかわかりません。
**キャッチされていない例外 'NSInvalidArgumentException'** とは何のことですか？。どうすればエラーが解消されるでしょうか。

**エラーコード↓**

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'NSLayoutConstraint for <GADBannerView: 0x7fdb4361d8f0; frame = (0 0; 320 50); clipsToBounds = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x6000028cd7e0>>: Constraint items must each be a view or layout guide.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ba238db __exceptionPreprocess + 331
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010afc6ac5 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   Foundation                          0x00000001080d5045 +[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:attribute:relatedBy:toItem:attribute:multiplier:constant:] + 0
    3   Foundation                          0x00000001080d5095 +[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:attribute:relatedBy:toItem:attribute:multiplier:constant:] + 80
    4   gokuTimer                           0x0000000105840db8 $sSo18NSLayoutConstraintC4item9attribute9relatedBy6toItemAD10multiplier8constantAByp_So0A9AttributeVSo0A8RelationVypSgAJ12CoreGraphics7CGFloatVAPtcfCTO + 424
    5   gokuTimer                           0x000000010584097f $s9gokuTimer14ViewControllerC09addBannerc2ToC0yySo09GADBannerC0CF + 1215
    6   gokuTimer                           0x000000010583ede7 $s9gokuTimer14ViewControllerC11viewDidLoadyyF + 455
    7   gokuTimer                           0x0000000105840164 $s9gokuTimer14ViewControllerC11viewDidLoadyyFTo + 36
    8   UIKitCore                           0x00000001140b00f7 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 1183
    9   UIKitCore                           0x0000000114013cf0 -[UINavigationController _updateScrollViewFromViewController:toViewController:] + 68
    10  UIKitCore                           0x0000000114013fe3 -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 146
    11  UIKitCore                           0x00000001140150a1 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 896
    12  UIKitCore                           0x0000000114016393 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 150
    13  UIKitCore                           0x0000000113ff7041 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 217
    14  UIKitCore                           0x0000000114b91e69 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1417
    15  QuartzCore                          0x0000000108fbdd22 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 173
    16  QuartzCore                          0x0000000108fc29fc _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 396
    17  QuartzCore                          0x0000000108fced58 _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 72
    18  QuartzCore                          0x0000000108f3e24a _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 328
    19  QuartzCore                          0x0000000108f75606 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 610
    20  UIKitCore                           0x00000001146cc2c3 __34-[UIApplication _firstCommitBlock]_block_invoke_2 + 128
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b98acbc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b98a480 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 336
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b984d04 __CFRunLoopRun + 1252
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b9844d2 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 626
    25  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010e9b42fe GSEventRunModal + 65
    26  UIKitCore                           0x00000001146b2fc2 UIApplicationMain + 140
    27  gokuTimer                           0x000000010584f3bb main + 75
    28  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010ce62541 start + 1
    29  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

**ViewController**

```swift
import UIKit
import GoogleMobileAds

class ViewController: UIViewController, GADBannerViewDelegate {
        
    @IBOutlet weak var characterImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var timerlabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var startButton: UIButton!
        
    var bannerView: GADBannerView!
        
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        /*******ad**********************************************************/
        //In this case, we instantiate the banner with desired ad size.
         bannerView = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeBanner)
         addBannerViewToView(bannerView)
        
        bannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716"
        bannerView.rootViewController = self
        bannerView.load(GADRequest())
 
        bannerView.delegate = self
 
        /******************************************************************/
                
        SkillModal.shared.load()
        if let myTitle = SkillModal.shared.fastSkill(){ //This is change
        self.title = myTitle.title
            
        } else {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Title Name", message: "Please enter new name", preferredStyle: .alert)
            
            alert.addTextField(configurationHandler: nil)
          
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { _ in
                if let text = alert.textFields?[0].text {
                    self.title = text
                   
                    SkillModal.shared.add(Skill(title: text, goalCount: 60 * 60 * 20))
                    SkillModal.shared.save()
                }
            }))
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
            present(alert, animated:  true, completion: nil)
        }
        
        startButton.layer.cornerRadius = 25.0
        
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        
        guard let skill = SkillModal.shared.currentSkill else {
            return
        }
        self.title = skill.title
        timerlabel.text = secondsToGoalTimerLabel(skill.goalCount)

    }

    func addBannerViewToView(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
        bannerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(bannerView)
        view.addConstraints(
            [NSLayoutConstraint(item: bannerView,
                                attribute: .bottom,
                                relatedBy: .equal,
                                toItem: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor,
                                attribute: .top,
                                multiplier: 1,
                                constant: 0),
             NSLayoutConstraint(item: bannerView,
                                attribute: .centerX,
                                relatedBy: .equal,
                                toItem: view,
                                attribute: .centerX,
                                multiplier: 1,
                                constant: 0)
            ])
    }
    
    /// Tells the delegate an ad request loaded an ad.
    func adViewDidReceiveAd(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
        print("adViewDidReceiveAd")
    }
    
    /// Tells the delegate an ad request failed.
    func adView(_ bannerView: GADBannerView,
                didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: GADRequestError) {
        print("adView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
    
    /// Tells the delegate that a full-screen view will be presented in response
    /// to the user clicking on an ad.
    func adViewWillPresentScreen(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
        print("adViewWillPresentScreen")
    }
    
    /// Tells the delegate that the full-screen view will be dismissed.
    func adViewWillDismissScreen(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
        print("adViewWillDismissScreen")
    }
    
    /// Tells the delegate that the full-screen view has been dismissed.
    func adViewDidDismissScreen(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
        print("adViewDidDismissScreen")
    }
    
    /// Tells the delegate that a user click will open another app (such as
    /// the App Store), backgrounding the current app.
    func adViewWillLeaveApplication(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
        print("adViewWillLeaveApplication")
    }

/****************このコードで最初ダメでコメントアウトし、GoogleAddのドキュメントを見てViewDidLoad（）に書いた。*************************************************/
//    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
//        //広告インスタンス作成
//        var admobView = GADBannerView()
//        admobView = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeBanner)
//
//        //広告位置設定
//        let safeArea = self.view.safeAreaInsets.bottom
//        admobView.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.size.height - safeArea - admobView.frame.height)
//        admobView.frame.size = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: admobView.frame.height)
//
//        //広告ID設定
//        admobView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716"
//
//        //広告表示
//        admobView.rootViewController = self
//        admobView.load(GADRequest())
//        self.view.addSubview(admobView)
//    }
/*******************************************************************/
        
    }
```

**AppDelegate**

```swift
import UIKit
import Firebase

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
   
    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch
           
       // Use Firebase library to configure APIs
        FirebaseApp.configure()

       // Initialize Google Mobil Ads SDK, application ID を設定                            GADMobileAds.sharedInstance().start(completionHandler: nil)
        
        
       // if userDefaults.object(forKey: theFarstBoolKey) as! Bool == true //{       }
        
        return true
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }

}
```

**変更後コード**

```swift
import UIKit
import GoogleMobileAds


class ViewController: UIViewController, GADBannerViewDelegate {
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var characterImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var timerlabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var startButton: UIButton!
    
    
//    var bannerView: GADBannerView!
    
    var theView: UIView!
    
    var bannerView: GADBannerView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        /*******ad**********************************************************/
        //In this case, we instantiate the banner with desired ad size.
         bannerView = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeBanner)
         addBannerViewToView(bannerView)

        bannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716"
        bannerView.rootViewController = self
        bannerView.load(GADRequest())

        bannerView.delegate = self
   
        theView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)
        theView.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        view.addSubview(theView)
        
        theView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false //この一行は必要
        theView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 240).isActive = true
        theView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
        theView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        theView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
         /******************************************************************/
        
        
        SkillModal.shared.load()
        if let myTitle = SkillModal.shared.fastSkill(){ //This is change
        self.title = myTitle.title
            
        } else {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Title Name", message: "Please enter new name", preferredStyle: .alert)
            
            alert.addTextField(configurationHandler: nil)
          
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { _ in
                if let text = alert.textFields?[0].text {
                    self.title = text
                   
                    SkillModal.shared.add(Skill(title: text, goalCount: 60 * 60 * 20))
                    
                   
                    SkillModal.shared.save()

                }
            }))
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
            present(alert, animated:  true, completion: nil)
        }
        
        startButton.layer.cornerRadius = 25.0
        
        
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        
        guard let skill = SkillModal.shared.currentSkill else {
            return
        }
        self.title = skill.title
        timerlabel.text = secondsToGoalTimerLabel(skill.goalCount)

        
    }


    func addBannerViewToView(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
        bannerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(bannerView)
        view.addConstraints(
            [NSLayoutConstraint(item: bannerView,
                                attribute: .bottom,
                                relatedBy: .equal,
                                toItem: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor,
                                attribute: .top,
                                multiplier: 1,
                                constant: 0),
             NSLayoutConstraint(item: bannerView,
                                attribute: .centerX,
                                relatedBy: .equal,
                                toItem: view,
                                attribute: .centerX,
                                multiplier: 1,
                                constant: 0)
            ])
    }
    
    /// Tells the delegate an ad request loaded an ad.
    func adViewDidReceiveAd(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
        print("adViewDidReceiveAd")
    }
    
    /// Tells the delegate an ad request failed.
    func adView(_ bannerView: GADBannerView,
                didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: GADRequestError) {
        print("adView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
    
    /// Tells the delegate that a full-screen view will be presented in response
    /// to the user clicking on an ad.
    func adViewWillPresentScreen(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
        print("adViewWillPresentScreen")
    }
    
    /// Tells the delegate that the full-screen view will be dismissed.
    func adViewWillDismissScreen(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
        print("adViewWillDismissScreen")
    }
    
    /// Tells the delegate that the full-screen view has been dismissed.
    func adViewDidDismissScreen(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
        print("adViewDidDismissScreen")
    }
    
    /// Tells the delegate that a user click will open another app (such as
    /// the App Store), backgrounding the current app.
    func adViewWillLeaveApplication(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
        print("adViewWillLeaveApplication")
    }
    
//    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
//        //広告インスタンス作成
//        var admobView = GADBannerView()
//        admobView = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeBanner)
//
//        //広告位置設定
//        let safeArea = self.view.safeAreaInsets.bottom
//        admobView.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.size.height - safeArea - admobView.frame.height)
//        admobView.frame.size = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: admobView.frame.height)
//
//        //広告ID設定
//        admobView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716"
//
//        //広告表示
//        admobView.rootViewController = self
//        admobView.load(GADRequest())
//        self.view.addSubview(admobView)
//    }
    
    
    }
```

Comment: 例外の理由が`reason: 'NSLayoutConstraint for <...>: Constraint items must each be a view or layout guide.'`とあるのですから、チェックすべきは`NSLayoutConstraint`の部分でしょう。「`Constraint items`は`view`か`layout guide`かでないといけない」なんてエラーを出されている以上、viewでもlayout guideでもないものを`NSLayoutConstraint`に指定してしまっている、と言うところまではエラーメッセージから読み取れます。そこらへんをチェックしてみてください。

Comment: OOPer様お久しぶりです。 `NSLayoutConstraint` の部分はどこにあるのでしょうか、、、

Comment: 普通に検索すれば、何箇所か見つかりますが…。

Comment: 初めて検索の機能を使ったのですがこれは便利ですね！

Comment: 上下とも viewと layout guideを試したのですがダメみたいです。

Comment: まず、何を試したのかがわかりません。また、コードをいじる前にその部分をコメントアウトして、そこが原因であるかどうかは確かめられた(コメントアウトすればクラッシュしないことを確かめた)でしょうか？

Comment: やってないです。直ぐコードをいじってしまっていました

Comment: `addBannerViewToView(_:)` 内の `view.addConstraints（）` を全部コメントアウトしたところ。 `reason: 'The Google Mobile Ads SDK was initialized without an application ID. Google AdMob publishers, follow instructions here:` という違ったエラーが出てきました。アプリケーションIDなしで初期化されましたとあるのですが。Idは `bannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716"`に書いてあるのですがこれでなければ何のことを言っているのでしょうか？

Comment: [このディスカッションをチャットで続行](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97020/discussion-between-ahoahomarumaru-and-ooper)しましょう。

Comment: 伸展がありました。 `bannerView.load(GADRequest())`のコードをコメントアウトしたところほんの少しだけエラーによって停止させられる事が遅くなりました。

Comment: 私の意見ではチャットと言うのは現在のスタックオーバーフローのシステムで最悪のものであり、そちらに移行しろと言うのは退場勧告であろうと思っています。無事に解決できることを願っておりますが、今後こちらのスレでコメントさせていただくことはありません。悪しからず。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Generic Class NSLayoutAnchor](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nslayoutanchor)
ここに説明があるように、`NSLayoutConstraint`を直接使うのではなく、`NSLayoutAnchor`を代わりに使ってください。（ここではご質問に直接回答していませんが、おそらくこの方針でコードを書き直せば、不具合もなくなるのではないかと、楽観的な予測をしています）

以下のサンプルコードは、幅240、高さ80の`theView`を画面底部、x軸方向の中心にレイアウトするものです。

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var theView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        theView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)
        theView.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        view.addSubview(theView)

        theView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false //この1行はやはり必要
        theView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 240).isActive = true
        theView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
        theView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        theView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    }

}
```

Comment: エラー　`reason: 'NSLayoutConstraint for <GADBannerView: 0x7fd0c1519b40; frame = (0 0; 320 50); clipsToBounds = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x60000286eee0>>: Constraint items must each be a view or layout guide.'`  となりました。書き足したコードは上に貼ます。

Comment: **〜を直接使うのではなく、〜を代わりに使ってください。** という表現に対し、**書き足し**という反応をするというのは、（こういう表現をして申し訳なく思いますが、）私の常識の範囲を超えます。